# Default html form focus without JavaScript

Tags: html, accessibility

Is it possible to set the default input focus on an HTML form without using JavaScript, for example:

```
<html>
  <form>
    Input 1: <input type="text" name="textbox1"/>
    <br/>
    Input 2: <input type="text" name="textbox2"/>
  </form>
</html>
```

I want to set the default focus to either of the text-boxes when the form loads without using JavaScript (as I want the behaviour to occur when a user has js disabled).

Answer (score 337, accepted):

You can do it in HTML5, but otherwise, you must use JavaScript.

HTML5 allows you to add `autofocus` to your form element, eg:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" autofocus />
```

This does work in browsers which support HTML5 (Or rather, browsers which support this particular part of HTML5) but as you know, not everybody can use it yet.

Answer (score 24):

Something to be aware of ... if you set a focused form element, then anyone using Assisted Technology (AT) like a screen reader will need to back up to see menus and any other content that is before the focused field.

A preferred method, in my opinion , is to not set focus to any field, except a skip-link if its available. That gives them the option to skip into the pages content or read the page from the top down.

Comment: Adding a skip-link which is visually hidden too, but accessible via screenreaders would be great!

Comment: I have so much to learn about accessibility. Thank you for adding this answer to help the rest of us learn!

Comment: Note, however, that this can also degrade experience for many users, especially if the input field provides the main functionality. Consider Google’s home page, for example.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, without Javascript you can't guarantee a default field. An alternative option you might want to try, if you have multiple fields that a user might want to access is using the `accesskey` attribute. This will essentially mean a user can return to either of the fields instantly later during browsing, which may come in handy for users of screen readers, etc...

Wikipedias article on this subject is quite useful - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key

Answer (score -3):

This is not possible without some form of scripting. Even Google's home page requires Javascript to focus the search field.

Comment: It is. Google just adds javascript for those browsers not supporting HTML5. Something worth considering in any app.

Answer (score -8):

You might be able to use the *tabindex* attribute and use the lowest value on the default textbox though. Check here for browser support:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/object/tabindex#compatibilitysection

The site suggests that

> (in almost all other cases—namely form controls and links—the tabindex has excellent support)

Comment: The "tabindex" attribute does not give automatic focus to any elements, not even an element with "tabindex=1". Pressing <tab> (or a click) is required give focus to the first element in the tab sequence.