# Making a form selected by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have this login page in my rails app. I want the first form which is for the username to be allready selected by default, when I enter the page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: if you mean focused, then this isn't related to rails.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166423/default-html-form-focus-without-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `autofocus: true` option to the form helper:

```
= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true
```