# HTML select tag attribute similar to autofocus

Tags: html

Is there any attribute for select tag in HTML like autoFocus for textbox ?
    
So that select should have default focused. Means I want to do autofocus for select tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166423/default-html-form-focus-without-javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autofocus` in the select tag as follows:

```html
<select autofocus>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

If you run the code snippet and then immediately press enter or the down arrow then you will see that the select has the focus on the page. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: autofocus did not work with select tag, it works good with text.

Comment: Can you plz add an example here ?

Comment: Sorry autofocus attribute is for input tag not for select tag.