# make select tag focus on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autofocus

I am trying to make autofocus on select tag on page load. But I am not able to do that with `autofocus` tag.

```
 <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="sel_bookID" id="sel_bookID" autofocus="autofocus" >
    @foreach ($arrayname as $data)                                       
        <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->BookID }}</option>                                                      
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here `autofocus="autofocus"` is not working. I refered to the question [HTML select tag attribute similar to autofocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137297/html-select-tag-attribute-similar-to-autofocus) but can not get any appropriate solution. Can we do autofocus using `javascript` or `jquery` for `select` tag?

Comment: by focus do you mean that on page load drop down should get open?

Comment: No just focus on the select tag, then we can use tab for opening the dropdown. Thank You!

Comment: if that is the case you already have focus attribute set. The focus is there and you can change vales by pressing up or down arrow keys or press enter to show the drop down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery focus on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814361/jquery-focus-on-load)

Comment: @Ahmad I already mentioned that autofocus property is not working. Thats why I posted my problem. Thank You!!!

Comment: its working for me

Comment: It should work, if you haven't used focus property in other elements. [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/RajanPaneru/upac3gt4/1/). 

If you want to force, then you can use `$(document).ready` or `setTimeout` then `focus` method to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/#focus) method. When the DOM gets ready you need to set the focus on the `select`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sel_bookID').focus();
});
```

Or using pure javaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    document.getElementById('sel_bookID').focus();
}, false);
```

Comment: Then you need to include the jQuery library in your project.

Comment: if jquery is not included you should try document.getElementById("sel_bookID").focus();

Comment: @nischalinn Edited my answer you can do it via pure JavaScript as well.