# How does browser/HTML decide where focus of cursor should be?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

If we don't manually set any of the HTML elements to be focused using javascript, how does HTML decide which element to be focused?

Comment: <input type="text" name="myInput" autofocus /> in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166423/default-html-form-focus-without-javascript

Comment: It follows the document's flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done via [tabindex attribute](https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/). By default it goes through focusable elements by position in page, but you can modify this behaviour.

From linked article:

Focusing non focusable elements:

> **tabindex=0**
>
> When tabindex is set to 0, the element is inserted into the tab order based on its location in the source code. **If the element is focusable by default there’s no need to use tabindex at all, but if you’re repurposing an element like a span or div, then tabindex=0 is the natural way to include it in the tab order.**

Ignore some focusable elements:

> **tabindex=-1**
>
> When tabindex is set to a negative integer like -1, it becomes programmatically focusable but it isn’t included in the tab order.

And finally: choose by yourself the order, no matter position of the element:

> **tabindex=1+**
>
> It imposes a tab order on the content that bears no resemblance to the expected tab order.

Comment: Thanks for elaborative answer!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "What tells the browser which elements can be focused?" then you are looking for the `tabindex` attribute. Adding this to an element will allow an input device (i.e. mouse, keyboard) to trigger a focus state on the element.

If your question is basically, "how are things focused on?", this is done using an input device, i.e. mouse, and keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean when the page loads you can use the autofocus attribute

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is actually no element that gets the focus by default.

We can check this pretty easily by creating a simple site and log

```
document.querySelectorAll(":focus")
```

to the console.

You will see that it will return an empty array, meaning that no element is focused.