# Have password field and a next button displayed via c/cgi-bin/html. I want the focus to be in the password field when screen is displayed

Tags: html, c, cgi-bin

[Initial screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd9ZV.jpg)

a user logging into the displayed screen has to press tab or click in the password field to get to the password field and type the password. I want to hav focus in the password input box when the screen is displayed so that the user can immediately type the password.

I am using a cgi form in c with the HTML/cgi-bin command 
and the password line is defined with:

These along with other code not relevant to the problem results in the attached screen being displayed.
I have found out how to preset a radio button selection and a checkbox but have not found how to give focus to a password or text field on display of the screen. The fact that I can get there with a tab indicates that the focus is somewhere, just not where it needs to be.
Anyone able to help? As is probably obvious I have been using these sorts of commands for only a short time but learn quickly. So please do not flame me for my ignorance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default html form focus without JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166423/default-html-form-focus-without-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("HTMLElementID").focus();</script>` where HTMLElementID=id of the field in the form (you must insert id="..." on the field in the form)

Put this before closing the body tag of the page.