# How do I force focus on a texfield when the DOM is ready in iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, ios

How does one in iOS (iPad/iPhone/iPod) to force the focus on an input element when the DOM is ready, with jQuery?

I've got a barcode webpage, that needs the focus to be immediately on a textfield.

I've found jQuery will do just fine for IE,Firefox,Chrome,Safari,Android but iOS mobile Safari, and iOS mobile Chrome won't let me focus on a textfield when the DOM is ready.

This is what I have so far:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('#barcode').focus();
});
```

Any ideas, guys/gals?

Comment: Nothing to show - all the code is thus:

`$j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('#barcode').focus();

});`

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible on Mobile Safari and presumably Chrome on iOS. See the following duplicate SO questions:

- [How do I focus an HTML text field on an iPhone (causing the keyboard to come up)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979309/how-do-i-focus-an-html-text-field-on-an-iphone-causing-the-keyboard-to-come-up)
- [Mobile Safari: Javascript focus() method on inputfield only works with click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click)

Running [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYsv5/1/embedded/result/) in Mobile Safari or Chrome on iOS will confirm this answer.

```
$("input").focus(); // Does not focus input in Mobile Safari or Chrome on iOS.
```

This code has been tested (and failed) in Mobile Safari and Chrome on iOS on the following devices:

- iPhone 4 running iOS 7 beta 6
- iPad 2 running iOS 6.1.3
- iOS Simulator running iOS 7 beta 5