# JS / jQuery - Force a click on a textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

So I've looked around at doing this as I need to get around an iOS bug, and none of my simulated clicks seem to work. I'm trying to manually focus on a textarea element but to do that I need to manually simulate a click on said textarea element. So here's what I've tried:

```
$('#text-input')[0].click();
$('#text-input').click();
$('#text-input').trigger('click');
$('#text-input').focus();
```

and

```
$('#text-input').on('click', function {
    $(this).focus();
});

$('#text-input').trigger('click');

$('#text-input').on('touchstart', function {
    $(this).focus();
});

$('#text-input').trigger('touchstart');
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="comment-input" class="comment-input" rows="1" maxlength="{{maxTextLength}}" ng-model="newMessage.content" placeholder="{{ messagePlaceholder }}" />
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't working?

Comment: can we see the HTML?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Ref [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979309/how-do-i-focus-an-html-text-field-on-an-iphone-causing-the-keyboard-to-come-up) and [2](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3016)

Comment: @Drakes I know it's a bug, I'm trying to do a workaround for it.

Comment: Some folks had progress with click for inputs, and could be extended to textarea. Ref [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728166/programatically-focus-on-next-input-field-in-mobile-safari) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204571/mobile-safari-javascript-focus-method-on-inputfield-only-works-with-click)

Comment: @Drakes I've already looked at these too and I'm still unsure of a solution

Answer (score 0):

try `.focus` instead of `click` like

```
$('#text-input').trigger('focus');
```

or Just

```
$('#text-input').focus();
```

**UPDATE**

You can try `setTimeout` which works in most case

```
$("#text-input").on("click", function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        $(event.target).select(); //or $(event.target).focus();
  }, 1); 
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

You can also try to use `touchstart` event like

```
//trigger touch on element to set focus
$("#text-input").trigger('touchstart'); 

//event handler to set the focus()
$('#text-input').on('touchstart', function () {
    $(this).focus();   // inside this function the focus works
});
```

Comment: I tried using `.focus()` already and it didn't work as it's an iOS bug. I realise there was a typo with the `.on` but this mistake wasn't made when coding :P

Comment: People copy and paste code from source to SO which makes us think that they are missing something syntactically when everything looks fine.. :) @germainelol

Comment: @germainelol updated the answer.. Kindly check and let me know.

Comment: Did you try `touchstart` or `timeout`?

Comment: I replaced the `.select()` with an alert and it is getting to the alert successfully, but again, if I try to replace that with anything else such as `focus` or `click`. It doesn't focus on the textarea.